# MySQL - Subtracting time from a duration (NOT DateTime)

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time

**Specs:** I'm using MySQL 5.6 with SQLWorkbench, SequelPro on OSX Yosemite

**Query background:** I'm trying to correct a set of `TIMESTAMPDIFF` durations for weekends and bank holidays. I have 2 stored procedures which are giving me the number of Saturdays, Sundays and Bank Holidays between two dates - these are working fine. To get the corrected `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, I therefore multiply the number of Saturdays, Sundays and holidays by 24 to get the number of hours to be subtracted, then subtract that number from the `TIMESTAMPDIFF`.

**Example:** As an example, if timestamp A is 14:00 on Friday and timestamp B is 14:01 on Tuesday, the raw `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is 96:01:00. Assuming Monday is holiday and the weekend is 48:00:00, I want to subtract 72:00:00 from 96:01:00, to get the 'business day difference' of 24:01:00.

**The problem:** When I do something like `"96:01:00" - "72:00:00" as date_sub_test`, I get `24`. I have lost all formatting, including the 01 minute.  Duration are not `DATETIME`, as they don't correspond to calendar dates, so I can't use `DATE_ADD` / `DATE_SUB`.

**The question:** How should I subtract time from a duration, retaining formatting and relevant base 60 system eg 60 minutes in an hour, not 100?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySql or Microsoft SQL Server or both?

Comment: MySQL - question edited - thanks

Comment: Have you tried the TIMEDIFF function? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Comment: Thanks Jaydee. TIMEDIFF seems to be what I am looking for. I also added in ABS() to make negative time differences positive, and MAKETIME() to create a time from an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Jaydee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417228/jaydee) mentions in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393855/mysql-subtracting-time-from-a-duration-not-datetime/41125092#comment52656615_32393855):

> Have you tried the TIMEDIFF function? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

TIMEDIFF was what I was looking for. I also added in ABS() to make negative time differences positive, and MAKETIME() to create a time from an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SEC_TO_TIME` and `TIME_TO_SEC` like

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC('96:01:00')-TIME_TO_SEC('72:00:00'))
```

you can use `ABS` like this

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(ABS(TIME_TO_SEC('96:01:00')-TIME_TO_SEC('172:00:00')))
```

Comment: This method of switching to seconds with `TIME_TO_SEC` for the calculation, then using `SEC_TO_TIME` to format the output also seems to work.